# NameError: name 'driver' is not defined. Did you mean: 'webdriver'?

Tags: python, selenium

For some reason I can't get the webpage to fire. I have literally copied the below code off a tutorial to see if it runs but I get this error:

```
>>> driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'driver' is not defined. Did you mean: 'webdriver'?
```

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/MyUsername/Downloads/chromedriver')

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
```

Comment: Are you having chromeDriver.exe in specified path? If yes then you need to specify complete path. Plus if you are having new selenium then you need to visit new documentation. The code you are following is for old versions of selenium. You want to stick that article then I will suggest to downgrade selenium using pip install selenium==3.7 command

Comment: chromedriver path will have nothing to do with the error you got. however, it's path may have something to do with a previous error you may have gotten and not noticed. was there any error when the `driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/MyUsername/Downloads/chromedriver')` line was executed?